# Van Der Grinten projection repeating past 180 degrees

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, coordinate-system

I have a ArcGIS map with this projection, but I want to project past 180 degress
so that the data is repeating, like here:
[image]

How can I do that? I'm using ArcGIS 10.2. 
I'm welcome to try new software if that's not possible with ArcMap.

Comment: Not possible with ArcGIS because we hold to a 360 longitude limit. And I think this is a duplicate but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

I think we should take the word of [@mkennedy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/963/mkennedy?tab=profile) that this is:

> Not possible with ArcGIS because we hold to a 360 longitude limit.

[@mkennedy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/963/mkennedy?tab=profile) suspects:

> this is a duplicate but couldn't find it

and neither can I.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the algorithm, the following will handle the area beyond 180°

For the forward projection (lat,lon to x,y):

```
theta = asin(2.0 * fabs((localPoint.lat * deg2rad) / pi));

al = 0.5 * fabs((pi / (localPoint.lon * deg2rad)) - ((localPoint.lon * deg2rad) / pi));

*** ADDED ***

if (localPoint.lon < -180.0 || localPoint.lon > 180.0)
    al = al * -1.0;

*** 

asq = al * al;
sinth = sin(theta);
costh = cos(theta);
g = costh / (sinth + costh - 1.0);
gsq = g * g;
m = g * (2.0 / sinth - 1.0);
msq = m * m;
con = pi * r * (al * (g - msq) + sqrt(asq * (g - msq) * (g - msq) - (msq + asq) * (gsq - msq))) / (msq + asq);

if ((localPoint.lon * deg2rad) < 0)
    con = -con;
*x = con;
```

And for the inverse projection (x,y to lat,lon):

```
con = pi * r;
xx = x1 / con;
yy = y1 / con;
xys = xx * xx + yy * yy;
c1 = -fabs(yy) * (1.0 + xys);
c2 = c1 - 2.0 * yy * yy + xx * xx;
c3 = -2.0 * c1 + 1.0 + 2.0 * yy * yy + xys * xys;
d = yy * yy / c3 + (2.0 * c2 * c2 * c2 / c3 / c3 / c3 - 9.0 * c1 * c2 / c3 / c3) / 27.0;
a1 = (c1 - c2 * c2 / 3.0 / c3) / c3;
m1 = 2.0 * sqrt( -a1 / 3.0);
con = ((3.0 * d) / a1) / m1;
if (fabs(con) > 1.0)
{
   if (con >= 0.0)
      con = 1.0;
   else
      con = -1.0;
}

*** ADDED ***

// if the point is more than 2 units from the center then it wraps

if (sqrt(x1 * x1 + y1 * y1) > 2.0)
    th1 = (2.0 * pi - acos(con)) / 3.0;
else

***

th1 = acos(con) / 3.0;

if (y >= 0)
   lat = (-m1 * cos(th1 + pi / 3.0) - c2 / 3.0 / c3) * pi * rad2deg;
else
   lat = -(-m1 * cos(th1 + pi / 3.0) - c2 / 3.0 / c3) * pi * rad2deg;

if (fabs(xx) < EPSILON)
    lon = cLon + 180;
else
    lon = (pi * (xys - 1.0 + sqrt(1.0 + 2.0 * (xx * xx - yy * yy) + xys * xys)) / 2.0 / xx) * rad2deg;
```